# showModalBottomSheet() not opening a bottom modal in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The showModalBottomSheet does not pop up a modal. I am new to flutter and dart but I think this is a problem, I would not any help. The simple page to pop a bottom sheet modal below.. did not work.

````
```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return new MaterialApp(
           home: new Scaffold(
             appBar: new AppBar(title: const Text('Modal bottom sheet')),
             body: new Center(
               child: new RaisedButton(
                child: const Text('SHOW BOTTOM SHEET'),
               onPressed: () {
                 showModalBottomSheet<void>(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) 
               {
            return new Container(
              child: new Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                child: new Text('This is the modal bottom sheet. Click anywhere to dismiss.',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    fontSize: 24.0
                  )
                )
              )
            );
          });
        }
      )
    )
  )
);
````

}
}
    ```

I cannot seem to figure out what the probl

Comment: Add your body to a new stateless widget then call showBottomSheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your body to a new widget.

[Dart Pad Example](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b)

Full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home: new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(title: const Text('Modal bottom sheet')),
            body: Sheet(), // new Widget
   ));
  }
}


class Sheet extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Center(
      child: new RaisedButton(
          child: const Text('SHOW BOTTOM SHEET'),
          onPressed: () {
            // Show sheet here
            showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return new Container(
                    child: new Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                      child: new Text(
                        'This is the modal bottom sheet. Click anywhere to dismiss.',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                            fontSize: 24.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Mostly it does not work because it has a problem of context

**make sour you give context**

```
_showBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new Container(
        child: new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: new Text(
            'This is the modal bottom sheet. Click anywhere to dismiss.',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: new TextStyle(
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                fontSize: 24.0),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To solve this kind of problem, you have to delay triggering the modal bottomsheet.

```
    onTap :() {
    Future.dalayed(Duration(seconds: 0).then((value) {
      showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
       builder: (BuildContext context) {
       return new Container(
        child: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
         child: new Text(
        'This is the modal bottom sheet. Click anywhere to dismiss.',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: new TextStyle(
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            fontSize: 24.0),
                   ),
                  ),
                 );
                });

              }

          }
```