# How to make this Bottom Sheet open?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, bottom-sheet

I was following a few tutorials and followed exactly to the tee, to create a bottom sheet, but it just doesn't open.

The only message i get is 'I/flutter ( 6593): Another exception was thrown: No MaterialLocalizations found' in the debug console

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Widget buildButtonSheet(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      height: 300,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Sheet Opened'),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Bottom Sheet Example',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Bottom Sheet Example'),
        ),
        body:         
        Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Bottom Sheet'),
            onPressed: () {

              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context, 
                builder: buildButtonSheet);

            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried one of the solutions posted before ([showModalBottomSheet() not opening a bottom modal in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59608599/showmodalbottomsheet-not-opening-a-bottom-modal-in-flutter))but didn't work.

I tried out using different emulators as ChatGPT suggested also, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer from another post [Why is the showModalBottomSheet() function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889558/why-is-the-showmodalbottomsheet-function-not-working)

Basically i have to add the MaterialApp to the top. Here's the working code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: MyApp(),
      ),
    );

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  void buildButtonSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          height: 300,
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Sheet Opened'),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Bottom Sheet Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Bottom Sheet'),
          onPressed: () {
            buildButtonSheet(context); // Call the buildButtonSheet method here
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And for some reason, i believe the old code might work for some specific circumstances... maybe in a different version or something as another user posted that the code was working after testing it out. Also, the tutorial that i was learning from also showed the code was working well, so i'm not sure why it worked for them and not for me... If anyone could tell me why, it would be great to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Your `context`, doesn't yet have a `MaterialLocalizations` widget in the widget tree, [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56275595/no-materiallocalizations-found-myapp-widgets-require-materiallocalizations-to). So this means that you need 'new' context, and you have two possible solutions. You either move your body into new widget, or you can wrap body with `Builder` widget.

Solution with Builder widget:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Bottom Sheet Example',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Bottom Sheet Example'),
        ),
        body: Builder(
          builder: (ctx) {
            return Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Bottom Sheet'),
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(context: ctx, builder: buildButtonSheet);
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Solution with NewWidget:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Bottom Sheet Example',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Bottom Sheet Example'),
        ),
        body: NewWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewWidget({
    super.key,
  });

  Widget buildButtonSheet(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      height: 300,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Sheet Opened'),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Bottom Sheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: buildButtonSheet);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried 1st and 2nd option, didn't work. Will check out the link provided.  Both with same message 'No MaterialLocalizations found.'. Please share if you have more solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here is the full code for you, this runs for me. Hope it will work for you also.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

//bottomsheet
  void openCustomSettings(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Color.fromARGB(115, 231, 231, 231),
                Color.fromARGB(77, 131, 131, 131),
              ],
              begin: Alignment.center,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30),
            ),
          ),
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text('Your text'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Bottom Sheet Example',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Bottom Sheet Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Bottom Sheet'),
            onPressed: () => openCustomSettings(context), //pass it here with **context** also
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. Same 'No MaterialLocalizations found.' message. Please share if you have other solutions.

Comment: ok, checking again.

Comment: I just copy and paste your code on my VScode, it's running correctly, I think you should open your terminal and run "flutter clean" then "flutter run"

This is what I get from your code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1foLMGjp0SjyAhsDWqc-_zsAX9052DCYu/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Performed flutter clean and run... still didn't work. It's interesting how using same code worked for you but not for me. I wonder what's the reason behind this... different version perhaps? But i found a solution from another post using different code. I will add as answer shortly. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Are you using the latest flutter version?

Comment: Are you using the latest flutter version? My flutter version is 3.10.2, Dart 3.0.2, DevTools 2.23.1