# Why is this Bottom Sheet code working for others but not for me?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, bottom-sheet

I posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76849843/how-to-make-this-bottom-sheet-open) earlier using the following code, where i could not get my BottomSheet to open. However it worked for the person who was explaining to me on the video and it also worked for another user who replied me. I had to use another workaround to solve it, but i'd still like to know why isn't it working for me.

Here are my versions:
Flutter 3.10.2 | Dart 3.0.2 | DevTools 2.23.1.

Could someone please try out the code in a VS Code? The only feedback i get is from the Debug Console is
"I/flutter ( 4269): Another exception was thrown: No MaterialLocalizations found."

My workaround was to place the MaterialApp above and it worked. But i'd like to know why the original code doesn't work as i can't keep up with the tutorial i'm learning from if i can't be in sync with it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Widget buildButtonSheet(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      height: 300,
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Sheet Opened'),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Bottom Sheet Example',
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Bottom Sheet Example'),
        ),
        body:         
        Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Bottom Sheet'),
            onPressed: () {

              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context, 
                builder: buildButtonSheet);

            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I also get the `No MaterialLocalizations found.` exception. This is on macos 10.15.7, flutter 3.10.6, dart 3.0.6, from the CLI: `flutter run`. Not the system you wanted tested; I'm just lending moral support! :-)

Comment: If your structure is similar to mine, try moving the MaterialApp higher as it worked for me. But i'm here to pursue the truth on why the original code isn't working for me but it is for others. If you're looking for the same thing, let's hope someone can give us the answer. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the way BuildContext works in Flutter. **If you create a MaterialApp and then try to use the context in the same widget to show modal button, it will throw the error that occurred.**

For Ex:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Foo"),
          onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context, 
                builder: buildButtonSheet),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here it will throw the error because showModalBottomSheet requires a `MaterialLocalization` widget to be present in the widget tree. **The context you are providing to showModalBottomSheet is that of the widget in which MaterialApp widget is introduced. The way flutter's context works is that context looks for that widget above the current widget in tree. So, if in showModalBottomSheet, you are using the context of the widget in which MaterialApp is present, it will look for MaterialLocalizations widget above that widget(which in this case is not present).**

You can solve this issue using two ways:

1. **Using a Builder widget**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (ctx) => Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Foo"),
            onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
                context: ctx, 
                builder: buildButtonSheet),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Notice, in this case **I am using the context passed by the Builder widget (ctx) and not the default context**.

2. **You can extract the body part to another widget**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ANewWidget()
    );
  }
}

class ANewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Foo"),
        onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context, 
                builder: buildButtonSheet),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this case when using context **it will look at the widget tree and can successfully find the context in this widget's parent (In this case MaterialApp which introduces MaterialLocalizations in your case)**.